# action console simulator is not working and I cannot release my project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I'm working on making a conversation flow for smart speakers.
with google action builder console. And I'm using google cloud function for webhooks.

However, from this morning I cannot **change, simulate or release my google action project.**

1. Cannot save any changes in 'develop' menu on the google action console
   (error message : "An error occurred saving the scene")
   -> [screenshot img showing error in develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNmOH.jpg)

---

2. I cannot test any version in 'simulator' menu on the google action console
   (error message : "We're sorry, but somethin went wrong. Please try again")
   ->[screenshot showing error for save any changes in develop menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf0UW.jpg)

---

3. I can't release alpha or beta version in 'Deploy' menu on the google action console
   (error message : "Error submitting Assistant app")
   -> [screenshot showing error in release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCgmG.png)

---

No logs are found in google cloud function related to these problems.
And actually I didn't change anything since the recent release. How can I deal with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: another solution is to press ctrl+F5 or clear browser data & cache. This works pretty well specially if you have multiple tabs opened.

It is happening to more people. Maybe this can help:
See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849339/google-actions-platform-doesnt-works/70852381#70852381) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848855/sudden-error-when-deploying-any-google-action).

Google console doesn't offer much information about those errors. Only for the model ones. When that happens, and if your model is too big, I suggest to reduce it a little bit (or try with a well-known version that is working) and try deploying/running the simulator again. That way you can find out if it's your fault or Google is updating their system.

It is working again for me, after few hours throwing errors.