# Sudden error when deploying any Google Action

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

All my actions are giving errors when switching from 'Develop' tab to 'Test' tab, after a change.

Also with models that were working days ago.

After seeing that, I tried with another project with no changes, and the same error is thrown.

Does anybody know what is happening?

The error is not informative:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google support team answered me. The problem was the Chrome cache.

Too many deploys while exploring the web console may cause this issue.

**Solution:**
Delete cache or press `ctrl+f5` in Chrome to completely refresh the website. Then you can change tabs or create releases again.